# Dynamics CRM 2011 web resource not showing in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamics-crm-2011, html

I have implemented this Solution:
http://crm2011lookuppreview.codeplex.com/

It works great in Outlook and on IE, but the previews don't show at all on Chrome. I tried changing the jQuery .show() commands to a .style.display = "block" but nothing. Below is the JavaScript included in the solution that is responsible for building the HTML and displaying it. It seems that Chrome doesn't load the web resource at all because on IE at least, the outline of the resource is visible and then the data comes and fills in that outline. In Chrome, there's just blank space. But it could be how Chrome renders, I dunno...

```
//LookupPreviewScript.js
﻿///<reference path="XrmPage-vsdoc.js"/>
var XrmPage;
var popWindow;
var _VerticalLayout = "V";
var _HorizontalLayout = "H";
var _ZLayout = "Z";
var _NLayout = "N";

function LoadLookPreviewDelayed(webResourceId, lookupAttributeId, columnList, layout)
{
    myFn = function(){LoadLookPreview(webResourceId, lookupAttributeId, columnList, layout);}
    setTimeout(myFn, 2000);
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute(lookupAttributeId.toLowerCase()).addOnChange(myFn);
}

function FormHTMLTable(divTag, controlSet, layout)
{
    var str = "";
    if(layout == _VerticalLayout)
    {
        str = "<table><tbody>";
        for(var k=0; k < controlSet.length; k++){
        str += "<tr>";
        str += "<td class='headerCss'>" + controlSet[k].attributeDisplayName + "</td>";
        str += "<td>" + controlSet[k].attributeValue + "</td>";
        str += "</tr>";
        }
        str += "</tbody></table>";                              
    }
    else if(layout == _ZLayout)
    {
        str = '<table>';
        str += '<tbody>';
        for (var j = 0; j < controlSet.length; j++) {
            var index = j + 1;
            str += "<tr>"
            str += "<td class='headerCss'>" + controlSet[j].attributeDisplayName + "</td>";
            str += "<td>" + controlSet[j].attributeValue + "</td>";
            str += "<td class='seperator'></td>";
            if(index < controlSet.length)
            {
                str += "<td class='headerCss'>" + controlSet[index].attributeDisplayName + "</td>";
                str += "<td>" + controlSet[index].attributeValue + "</td>";
            }
            str += "</tr>"
            j++;
        }
        str += '</tbody>'
        str += '</table>';
    }
    else if(layout == _NLayout)
    {
        str = '<table>';
        str += '<tbody>';
        var half = Math.round(controlSet.length / 2)
        for (var j = 0; j < controlSet.length; j++) {
            var index = j + half;
            if (j < half) {
                str += "<tr>"
                str += "<td class='headerCss'>" + controlSet[j].attributeDisplayName + "</td>";
                str += "<td>" + controlSet[j].attributeValue + "</td>";
                str += "<td class='seperator'></td>";
                if (index < controlSet.length) {
                    str += "<td class='headerCss'>" + controlSet[index].attributeDisplayName + "</td>";
                    str += "<td>" + controlSet[index].attributeValue + "</td>";
                }
                str += "</tr>"
            }
        }
        str += '</tbody>'
        str += '</table>';
    }
    else 
    {
        str = "<table><thead><tr>";
        for(var k=0; k < controlSet.length; k++){
        str += "<th>" + controlSet[k].attributeDisplayName + "</th>";
        }
        str += "</tr></thead><tbody><tr>";
        for (var i = 0; i < controlSet.length; i++){
        str += "<td>" + controlSet[i].attributeValue + "</td>";
        }
        str += "</tr></tbody></table>";
     }
     divTag.innerHTML = str;
     $(divTag).slideDown(1000);
}

function LoadLookPreview(webResourceId, lookupAttributeId, columnList, layout)
{
   var divTag;
   var webResource = Xrm.Page.getControl(webResourceId);
   var columnSet = new Array();
   var columnHeaders = new Array();
   var controlSet = new Array();

   successCallBack =  function (attributeCollection) {
                 for(var k=0; k < controlSet.length; k++)
                 {
                    for (var i = 0; i < attributeCollection.length; i++) 
                    {
                        if(attributeCollection[i].attributeName == controlSet[k].attributeLogicalName)
                        {
                             controlSet[k].attributeValue = attributeCollection[i].attributeValue;
                             break;
                        }
                    }
                 }

                 FormHTMLTable(divTag, controlSet, layout);
          };

        errorCallBack =  function (error) {
             divTag.innerHTML = "<span class='error'>" + error.message + "</span>";
             $(divTag).slideDown(500);
         };

   if(webResource == null)
   {
       alert('No WebResource found with Id = ' + webResourceId);
   }
   else
   {
        divTag = document.getElementById(webResourceId).contentWindow.document.getElementById('lookupDIV');
        if(divTag != null)
        {
            divTag.display = "none";
            var columns = columnList.split('|');
            for(var i = 0 ; i < columns.length; i++)
            {
                var s = columns[i].split('#');
                var _control = new Object();
                _control.attributeDisplayName = s[0];
                _control.attributeLogicalName = s[1].toLowerCase().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
                _control.attributeValue = '';
                controlSet.push(_control);

                columnSet.push(s[1].toLowerCase().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''));
            }

            if(Xrm.Page.getAttribute(lookupAttributeId.toLowerCase()) != null && Xrm.Page.getAttribute(lookupAttributeId.toLowerCase()).getValue() != null)
            {
                var id = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(lookupAttributeId).getValue()[0].id;
                var entityName = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(lookupAttributeId).getValue()[0].entityType;
                SDK.RetrieveData.RetrieveRequestAsync(entityName, id, columnSet, successCallBack, errorCallBack);
            }
            else
            {
                FormHTMLTable(divTag, controlSet, layout);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Error in Loading Web Resource (DIV is NULL)")
        }
   }
}
```

I'm guessing it's something simple with how or when the DIVs are rendered but I'm not well versed in cross-compatibility.

Comment: I threw in an alert(divTag.innerHTML); before the jQuery .show(); and the alert shows in Outlook and IE but not in Chrome making me suspect that the web resources aren't loading at all or at least the jscript isn't firing

Comment: Is it possible to give a jsfiddle of this?  Also, I'm curious why you are using some jQuery calls, but then including statements like this `divTag = document.getElementById(webResourceId).contentWindow.document.getElementById('lookupDIV');` Wouldn't it be better to do this through a simple jQuery call?  And that might have something to do with your browser incompatibility.

Comment: I didn't write that code it's from the Solution I downloaded. I'm just trying to make it work for Chrome :P
As for jsfiddle I don't know how to do that for Dynamics CRM... besides just copy and pasting the aforementioned code into jsfiddle.
It looks like the only thing that jQuery is used for is the 
    $(divTag).slideDown(500);

which I changed to .show() because I didn't really want the slide effect. I could just as easily not use jQuery at all in this by taking those out, which I tried.. same thing. It's like the javascript just doesn't run or something

Comment: where is the jQuery.show method called, and what is in this call?  The script you posted are several distinct javascript functions, but it is unclear when or how they are being called.

Comment: ahh sorry Nate. LoadLookPreviewDelayed is called onLoad. I have replace the .show at the bottom of formHTMLTable with a .style.display = "block" and doesn't seem to have impacted how it works in IE and in Outlook but still nothing in Chrome.

Comment: How is the onLoad event being called?  And, have you tried putting an alert as the first statement in the `LoadLookPreviewDelayed` function?

Comment: I put an alert at the beginning of the three functions (LoadLookPreviewDelayed, formHTML, and LoadLookPreview) and formHTML doesn't seem to run in Chrome.

Comment: It looks like your javascript is not running at all (probably due to some error that chrome is choking on). Maybe try removing all these functions (or any other javascript) and see if you can get a simple alert to display in chrome. Then slowly add back in the javascript and see what breaks it. I'm still curious to see what your onLoad event looks like and is being triggered by.

Comment: Looks like it's not running the line
    SDK.RetrieveData.RetrieveRequestAsync(entityName, id, columnSet, successCallBack, errorCallBack);

must be problem with Chrome and the Dynamics CRM 2011 SDK.

Comment: I fixed it... with the help of http://crm2011lookuppreview.codeplex.com/discussions/431830

Funny I looked at the Discussions and saw that post but it didn't have any replies so I didn't even bother to look into it. Replacing the code in the specified js file fixed it for Chrome! Excellent.

Comment: Funny. now it does show in Chrome except that in the Vertical layout, for some reason it's showing the same value for all Value cells, but it is showing the correct value headers. interestingg....

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be some kind of incompatibility with Chrome and the Dynamics CRM 2011 SDK function SDK.RetrieveData. I just opened up the SDK.RetrieveData.js file included in the solution and replaced it with the code specified at this URL and she's working like a charm now!

http://crm2011lookuppreview.codeplex.com/discussions/431830